# make a custom grid view using rows and columns

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So, i am having a list of 12 elements and want to show them in column and rows like a grid.
**my code:-**

```
Widget grid({int crossAxisCount, int mainAxisCount,double width}){
    int count=-1;
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(mainAxisCount, (index){
        count++;
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(crossAxisCount, (index){
            count++;
            return serviceTile(
              serviceName: serviceNames[count],
              content: contents[count],
              fileName: serviceNames[count].toLowerCase(),
              width: width,
            );
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

but my code goes from index 0 to 13 but it should go till 11 so that that the following error is solved:-

```
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 12: 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Solution 1

  ```
  Widget grid({int crossAxisCount, int mainAxisCount,double width}){
    int count=-1;
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(mainAxisCount, (index){
       // count++;
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(crossAxisCount, (index){
            count++;
            return serviceTile(
              serviceName: serviceNames[count],
              content: contents[count],
              fileName: serviceNames[count].toLowerCase(),
              width: width,
            );
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
  ```
- Solution 2

  ```
  Widget grid({int crossAxisCount, int mainAxisCount,double width}){

    return Column(
      children: List.generate(mainAxisCount, (index1){

        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(crossAxisCount, (index2){
            int count = (mainAxisCount * index1) + index2;
            return serviceTile(
              serviceName: serviceNames[count],
              content: contents[count],
              fileName: serviceNames[count].toLowerCase(),
              width: width,
            );
          }),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
  ```